# 'Bind' wordpress page do custom plugin page

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a custom post type, and want to create a page to list posts of this post type.

I've seen many plugins that do same thing 'binding' to existing page, i.e. user create a normal wp page go to plugin's settings and set the created page. as a example the buddypress.

so what's the best way to 'bind' to a wp page ?

have tried `the_content` action, but apparently this action isn't called for pages...

```
add_action( 'the_content', array($this, 'renderCardListing') );
[...]
public function renderCardListing($content) {

  if ( is_single() ) {
    global $post;

     $card_listing_id = get_option('card_listing_page');

    if ( $card_listing_id != 'none' && $card_listing_id == $post->ID ) {
      $content = 'Test Working!';
    }

    return $content;
  }
}
```

Comment: the `the_content` hook should be able to be used for displaying plugin content in a page. I guess the trick is knowing when to register your 'the_content' plugin, or know when to simply return the unmodified `$content` from the first parameter.

Comment: @Scuzzy, not worked, any way there's a better way to do this ?

Comment: Can you include a sample of how you went about creating your hook function for `the_content`?

Comment: @Scuzzy added, obviously the function is a member of a class.

Comment: You may need to use `is_singular()` for a single page? and to also `return $content;` outside of any logic otherwise the filter will null your page content. Otherwise I've done similar approaches to replacing page content with filters like this. but I've got the page ID and compared it to my settings before registering `the_content` hook.

Comment: @Scuzzy In my case, is it possible i compare the page id before registering the hook ?